# Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Tags: plotting, piecewise

The code I am using to make my plot is:

```
DiscretePlot[
  Piecewise[{{1/((-2)^{x + 1}), x <= 3}, {1/32, x >= 4}}], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Also, how do I change to color of the points on the plot to red? I did

```
PlotStyle -> Red
```

It did not work.

Comment: Your input is not correct the first term should be: `{1/((-2)^(x + 1)), x <= 3}` and not `{1/((-2)^{x + 1}), x <= 3}` (beware the `{}`. You can track it down when you evaluate your function at `x=3` (you get a list!) and `x=4` you get a value.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `{ }` to bracket expressions in the Wolfram Language — only `( )`. Curly braces `{ }` are a shortcut for writing the function [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html).

So your code should be:

```
DiscretePlot[
  Piecewise[{{1/((-2)^(x + 1)), x <= 3}, {1/32, x >= 4}}], {x, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors corrected

```
DiscretePlot[Piecewise[{{1/((-2)^(x + 1)), x <= 3}, {1/32, x >= 4}}], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]